# How do I force an image to span 100% width in Squarespace?

Tags: html, css, squarespace

This is my [site.](http://speakingwithpictures.com/about/)

I'm trying to make the image at the top span 100% width of the browser.

However, i'd like the text to remain the 800px width it is now – and keep it centered.

Comment: which image you want to make 100%?

Comment: @Mr.Alien only the top image. The desk one.

Comment: still not getting it, you want the white desk image to stretch to 100% and cver up only the span are or the whole page?

Comment: @Mr.Alien I want the image to span the white desk image to stretch across the whole width of the browser. However, I want the type to stay as it is. [updated original question]

Answer (score 0):

at first sign you need check all `margin and padding`. And set all parent node `width:100%`

From your css i see

```
#site {
       margin: 0 auto;
       padding: 50px;
}
```

At least 50px from each side will be there

Comment: when I make everything 100% width the text bleeds to the edge. I want the text to remain the width it is now.

Comment: you need to wrap up your text in a div, give some width to the div and use `margin: auto;`

Comment: @Mr.Alien I thought you'd say that. Squarespace is a bit annoying in not letting you do that.